# Будет ли Service ждать выполнения потока?

Tags: java, android, service

Я имплементировал `Service` и мне нужно вызвать из него другой поток...

Дело в том, что у меня есть класс который используется в нескольких местах и он запускает поток при выполнении и вот мне нужно в одном месте сделать так, чтоб этот класс запускался в бекграунде...

Я вот, что сделал : импелементоровал сервис и хочу, чтоб он в своем бекграунде запускал мой класс в котором тоже реализован поток.

И я вот думаю, сервис запустит мой класс, мой класс запустит свой поток, сервис не знает, что там запустился поток и подумает, что работа закончена и умрет...

Так ли это?

И если да, то как можно сделать, чтоб он подождал?

Comment: Сервис сам по себе не умрет.

Comment: @metalurgus значит тут появляется другая проблема, мне ж тогда придется сервису как то показать, что уже все сделано и убить его... Как это сделать?

Comment: Нужно просто забиндить сервис, к этой активности где происходит задача. те bindActivity, и реализовать логику уже в методах активити. Так как ваш сервис необходимо закрывать после выполнения задачи, это хороший варинат, боле того у вас будут CallBack методы, в которых вы можете реализовать прямую обратную связь с Service.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei да в итоге я так и сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service будет жить пока его не прибьёт система, пока приложение не прибито юзером через FORCE STOP или пока вы сами его не остановите так:

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context,SERVICE_CLASS_NAME.class));
```

IntentService же по умолчанию действует не в UI потоке, в отличие от Service. И он самостоятельно помрёт когда закончит свою работу.

Comment: Не до конца понял насчет `IntentService` ... насколько я понимаю сервис в принцепи не работет в `UI` потоке, так как он работет в беке... Все что мне нужно выводить в  `UI` я делаю с помощью `runOnUiThread()`...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, просто попробуйте обратиться в сеть из сервиса не оборачивая запрос в другой поток - должен будет всплыть NetworkOnMainThreadExeption